# sql server blocking operators

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a list of all blocking operators? The only clear cut way I know to verify an operator is blocking is to check its properties and see if the data is sorted. Is this the only way to verify if an operator is blocking?IF not, what are the other ways of verifing that an operator is blocking?

**A blocking operator will need to process all rows before the data is passed on, while a non-blocking operator will pass rows to other operators and soon as it is read and processed.**

*below is definition of blocking vs non blocking*

Iterators that consume input rows and produce output rows at the same time (in the
GetRow method). We often refer to these iterators as “nonblocking.”

Iterators that consume all input rows (generally in the Open method) before producing
any output rows. We refer to these iterators as “blocking” or “stop-and-go.”

**WHY I NEED THIS INFO**
Mostly Curiosity and personal knowledge. I am not doing anything crazy with it. Just read about blocking vs non blocking operators and would like to know which operator does which.

**This is just for SSMS query plans**

Comment: What do you mean with 'blocking'?

Comment: @iswantosan updated with explanation of blocking vs non blocking operators

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about Showplan Logical and Physical Operators or SSIS Data Transformation Operators?

Comment: @jasonwhisman I am talking about showplan physical and logical operators

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I've never found anything to that end, unforftunately. All I ever do is look through MSDN's list of the operators and see which ones they indicate act that way (e.g., Eager Spool). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191158.aspx

Comment: @jasonwhisman Well that stinks. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: You might also want to explain why you need this information. If you need it for a specific reason, then someone may be able to give you an alternative way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Mostly Curiosity and personal knowledge. I am not doing anything crazy with it. Just read about blocking vs non blocking operators and would like to know which operator does which.

Comment: The subject is quite complicated. Some operators block on only one child (e.g. hash join). Some operators are normally non blocking but can also behave in a manner in which they are partially blocking (e.g. [nested loops join](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2009/03/18/optimized-nested-loops-joins.aspx))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you seen this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/06/19/637048.aspx ?
BTW, off the topic, stackoverflow seems to think that short answers can not be good. It has a 30 char minimum. :)
Looks like the original link is no longer valid. That blog article moved to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/properties-of-iterators).

Comment: Yeah. I guess what stackoverflow thinks is, that if you just post a link, you don't answer. Like for example if the link suddenly responds with a 403.... WOW, this link does :O.
This is old i know. Couldn't resist :)